# Data type errors in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have written some Verilog code in which a part of the code is as below:

```
int i;
          add_bit = 1'b0;
          for (i = 0; i < add_len; i++)
              add_bit = add_bit ^ (pat[4 + i]);
      end
```

After executing this, I am getting error as:

```
Do not use bit, byte, shortint, int and longint
```

Can you suggest any fixes here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` is a [SystemVerilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemVerilog#New_data_types) keyword (IEEE Std 1800).  To avoid that compile error, you either need to enable SV in your simulator, or you can replace `int` with the  `integer` keyword.